# geom_signif() overlaps asterisks/stars when manually plotting on a cluster bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, annotations, bar-chart

I created a dataframe that contains my asterisks and details to show statistics on the graph:

```
#this is index_df dataframe
xmin xmax y   sym
0.8  1.2  4.5 *
0.8  1.8  5.5 ****
1.2  2.2  6.5 *
1.8  2.2  4.5 *
```

And i apply it the the bargraph (i.e. plot) by geom_signif()

```
plot<- plot+geom_signif(
      data = index_df,
      aes(xmin=index_df$xmin_index,
          xmax=index_df$xmax_index,
          annotations=index_df$sym,
          y_position=index_df$y),
      textsize=6,size=0.7,vjust=0.5,manual=TRUE,inherit.aes = FALSE)}
```

The output is the following:
[image]

As you can see, geom_signif() has overlapped `*` when there should be three separate `*`.

I have tried hjust, but it didn't work

Comment: Do you mean "asterisks", aka "stars" in the R vocabulary?

Comment: @IRTFM, yes asterisks/stars. will change

Comment: I do not “see” the problem.

Comment: The problem is there should be 3 separate single asterisk/star, one above each column brackets per dark and light groups and then an asterisk on top of the bracket connecting the light shades columns of each group. But geom_signif() has combined all of the single asterisk to one asterisk on top of the bracket connecting the two lighter shade columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by using `geom_bracket()` from the `ggpubr` library instead.

```
plot<- plot+geom_bracket(
      aes(xmin=index_df$xmin_index,
          xmax=index_df$xmax_index,
          label=index_df$sym,
          y.position=index_df$y),
      data=index_df,inherit.aes = FALSE)}
```